# Divs display according browser window size

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a container div and inside it I have a lot of other divs. The container width is 1100px and it's centered in the middle of the browser window. The other divs that are inside the container are side by side. In this image example I illustrated three inside divs, but can be more above them (divD, divE, etc).

[image]

If the browser window is resized a little, but not cut the container div, nothing change.

[image]

The problem is that when the browser window is rezied a lot, and cut the container div.

[image]

What I want is to, in this cases, resize the container div width to fit in the browser window and make the inside divs of the container jump down to the next line, like this:

[image]

How can I do that? Perhaps bootstrap is useful here?

My html so far:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="inside-div">
    </div>
    <div class="inside-div">
    </div>
    <div class="inside-div">
    </div>
    <div class="inside-div">
    </div>
```

```
.inside-div {
   width: 80px;
   height: 100px;
   background: green;
   margin-left: 35px;
   margin-top: 30px;
   display: inline-block;
}

#container {
   background: red;
   width: 400px;
   height: 500px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/b8do1xs8/

Comment: Are you allowed to use javascript?

Comment: Yes I can use Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on your container change

```
#container {
  background: red;
  width:100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

max-width to have it stop at 400px (or 1100px in your case);
width:100% to have it fit in screen when it's less than max-width

Comment: Thanks it works. But can you take a look at this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/b8do1xs8/5/? If I have this other div (blue background) at the right side, how can I make this div not be moved down on window resize but instead make the content div (red background) decrease?

Comment: @PedroEstevao You mean a kind of sidebar? Take a look at http://clubmate.fi/100-percent-height-columns-fixed-width-sidebar-pure-css-solutions-to-commons-fluid-layout-problems/

Also, you should use class instead of id more often! https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

Answer (score 1):

You want to give your container a percentage instead of a fixed width. Try

```
#container {
   background: red;
   width: 90%;
   height: 500px;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using max-width instead of width will improve the browser's handling of small windows.

```
#container {
  background: red;
  max-width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```